# Hide cached objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, objectinstantiation

I'm not sure if "cached" is a correct term for this one. Maybe I should use "instantiated" instead. However, say I want to "cache" several objects, to save some resources:

```
var $foo = $("#foo"),
$bar = $("#bar");
```

Now, if I want to hide them, can I use a one-liner instead of:

```
$foo.hide();
$bar.hide();
```

I reckon that this one is quite simple (read: "stupid"), but hey... I can't figure it out all by myself...

Comment: Have you tried? (yes you can)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add) to roll up a bunch of jQuery objects and selectors:

```
$foo.add( $bar ).add('.someclass').add( $other_objects_or_selectors ).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for `.add()`. It saved the day! =)

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
$.each([$foo, $bar], function(i, v) { 
  v.hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple selectors in jQuery separated with comma:

```
$("#foo, #bar").hide();
```

Comment: Of course, but I want to combine instantiated objects, something like `$.($foo, $bar).hide()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for many id's, maybe do something like:

```
items = ['foo', 'bar'];
cache = {};
$.each(items, function(i,key) {
    cache[key] = $('#' + key);
    cache[key].hide();
});
```

Then later on access the 'cache' like `cache['foo']`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class for all these elements and then hide by the class

```
$('#foo').addClass('toHide'); 
//Later
$('.toHide').filter(':visible').hide();
```

Comment: Class selectors are way slower than id selectors. I can always define a class, but it's a no-no IMHO.